# JS 2D collision rectangle with map

Tags: javascript, math, 2d, collision-detection

I have a player of 50 width and 30 height. My problem is calculating the collision correctly. I figured how to do this by checking the middle of the player (you can see it below), but I have problem with accounting for his width and height as well - half of him will go through the wall before he stops.

The map is divided into many squares (for example 100x100 pixels, the 100 is called tileSize) and between the squares there either is a wall or isn't (each square is an object which can have top or/and left true, when true, you cannot pass that side of the square - there is a wall).

the collision detection (item == player):

```
//inner walls - map collisions
var tileX = Math.floor(item.pos.x / this.tileSize);
var tileY = Math.floor(item.pos.y / this.tileSize);

var tileX = Math.floor(item.pos.x / this.tileSize);
var tileY = Math.floor(item.pos.y / this.tileSize);

if(tileX == item.last_X && tileY == item.last_Y){return;} //if its the same tile..

var colidedX = false;
var colidedY = false;
/* Check X */
if (item.last_X > tileX) {
    if (this.map[item.last_Y][item.last_X].left) {
        item.pos.x = item.last_X * this.tileSize;
        colidedX = true;
    }
}
if (item.last_X < tileX) {
    if (this.map[item.last_Y][item.last_X+1].left) {
        item.pos.x = (item.last_X+1) * this.tileSize;
        colidedX = true;
    }
}   
/* Check Y */
if (item.last_Y > tileY) {
    if (this.map[item.last_Y][item.last_X].top) {
        item.pos.y = item.last_Y * this.tileSize;
        colidedY = true;
    }
}
if (item.last_Y < tileY) {
    if (this.map[item.last_Y+1][item.last_X].top) {
        item.pos.y = (item.last_Y+1) * this.tileSize;
        colidedY = true;
    }
}   

if(colidedX == false){
    item.last_X = tileX;
}
if(colidedY == false){
    item.last_Y = tileY;
}
```

I have an idea how I could do it, but it would be very complicated and long, so I thought there must be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Did you try adding player's width and height to its position when checking for collisions?